# fetch data from database using ajax codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

In this code after clicking on button it should fetch the data from database and display it dynamically within appropriate div using jquery and ajax but i am not getting any output, below is my code:

**controller**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Afcks extends CI_Controller 
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('afcks_search','am');        
}
function index()
{
    $this->load->view('afcks_home');
}
function search_course()
 {
        $result=$this->am->search_course();
        echo json_encode($result);
 }
}
```

**model**

```
 class Afcks_search extends CI_Model
 {
    function search_course()
    {
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT course_name FROM courses");
        return $query->result();
     }
}
```

**view**

```
 <head>
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>/afcks/search_course";
                type:"POST",
                dataType:"json",
                data:req,
                success:
                function(data)
                {
                    var str='';'
                    str+='<ul>';
                    for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++)
                    {
                        str+='<li>'+data.course+'</li>';
                    });
                    str+='</ul>';
                    $('#course').html(str);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>  
 </head>
 <body> 
<button> click me </button>
<div id="course"> </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey, a) Do you have CSRF enabled? b) Are there any errors in the error console? c) When viewing the developer console, can you see the request and it's response?

Comment: no m not getting any error on console

Comment: Please share complete code along with file names.

Comment: okay, now i have share my complete code

Comment: @ArchanaGupta - If you go to the URL manually via the browser, do you see anything? i.e. `http://localhost/afcks/search_course`

Comment: [{"course":"Excel"},{"course":"Adv Excel"},{"course":"ajax"},{"course":"sql"},{"course":"php"}] - i got this output,an array of courses @Gavin

Answer (score 1):

You are requesting wrong url from ajax. In your controller method name is `search_course` So change you ajax url to:

```
url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>/afcks/search_course";
```

Also change `obj` to `data` as you are retrieving result into `data`

```
for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++)
{
      str+='<li>'+data.course_name+'</li>'; //<----change here
 });
```

Comment: i did all the changes but still not getting any output.

Answer (score 0):

please copy my code, also try to change base url and json data conversion

```
<head>
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
                 var base=<?php echo base_url(); ?>;
            $.ajax({

                url:base+"/afcks/search_course";//also try "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/afcks/search_course" i dont think it's correct.
                type:"POST",
                dataType:"json",
                data:req,
                success:
                function(data)
                {
                   var responseData = $.parseJSON(data);//convert string to json, i know you datatype is set to 'json' still want to cross check. 
                    var str='';
                    str+='<ul>';
                    $(function() {
                        $.each(responseData, function(i, item) {
                             str+='<li>'+item.course_name+'</li>';
                        });
                    })
                    str+='</ul>';
                    $('#course').html(str);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>  
 </head>
 <body> 
<button> click me </button>
<div id="course"> </div>
</body>
```

hope this will work !

Comment: sorry for bothering you multiple times, let me try one more time

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>/afcks/course";
```

to

```
url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>afcks/search_course";
```

and

```
var str='';'
str+='<ul>';
```

to

```
var str='<ul>';
```

And

```
for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++)
{
    str+='<li>'+data.course+'</li>';
});
```

to

```
$.each(data,function()
{
    str+='<li>'+this.course_name+'</li>';
}
```

And remove

```
data:req,
```

Comment: also change 
$result=$this->am->search_course();
to
$result=$this->afcks_search ->search_course();

Comment: still nothing happened

Comment: send your directory to akshay.kapoor392@gmail.com